# When modeling meshes, some functions don't seem to complete

Tags: mesh

I'm having a problem with several functions. A good example is trying to remove the intersection between two meshes. I've added a sphere and a cube, moved them so they partially overlapped, then selected one, then used ctrl-lmb to select the other, hit tab to get into the edit mode, then picked Faces->Intersect (Boolean) I get a dialog box (is that the right term for it) with several settings for the intersection, but after trying different settings, I don't see any way to complete what I'm doing.

Here's a screen shot:
[image]

I have tried different ways to multi-select the objects and it hasn't helped. In this case, since it's just a testing/learning experiment, I just want to remove the intersected area from either the sphere or the cube - doing either would show me I've learned to do it correctly.

I know I am either doing something wrong or not finishing the process. So what do I do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go into edit mode with two objects, they will not interact with eachother when you try to use the *Intersect (Boolean)* as far as i know. But if you go into edit mode with only the cube selected, and then add a sphere when while in edit mode. Then you will be able to use that sphere as a boolean object.

I would recommend you to use the *Boolean Modifier* instead. Add it on the object you want to cut (intersect or difference) or append the object shape and put the object you want to cut/append with in the Object box.

[image: Add boolean modifier on object you want to cut/append to]
[image: 3D view example]
Boolean with difference from the Sphere. (Sphere hidden):
[image: Boolean done (difference)]

Comment: Wow - you're there for every question tonight! ;) Odd, but even using the Boolean modifier, it comes up, I can click the options, and I see the outline of the cube change, but I don't see a way to make it permanent. If I move the sphere away, the result is gone.

Comment: @Tango That's what modifiers are for: non-destructive workflows where the original mesh is preserved. As long as you use the modifier, you can make changes to it, reposition the cutting object etc. in case you want to rearrange something. If you want to make the changes permanent (i.e. destructive because they "destroy" the original mesh) you have to apply the modifier. Then you can remove the object you used to change the mesh.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: I couldn't find the Apply button, which I saw in screenshots on various pages, but I found that I can get to Apply by clicking the triangle. I knew there was a way to do that, since I've done it before - a year or more ago!

Comment: Okay, I have it working with the Boolean Modifier and can make it permanent. I can't get it to work by picking Mesh in the menu in Edit Mode. That'd make things go faster if I could do that. I just don't see anything applied when I use the command in edit mode. Is there some way to specify to apply the edit?

Comment: @Tango Most of the modifiers cannot be applied in _Edit Mode_, you have to apply them in _Object Mode_. I guess you have seen the _Apply Button_ you are referring to in an older Blender version. Or you mean the _Apply All_ button, for that you have to enable the _Modifier Tools_ addon in the preferences.

Comment: @Tango I had some time on my hands last night so i thought id help out some people if i could :). I see Gordon managed to help you out with the last questions. Good stuff :)